# Adding a new parameter to function

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have a function $y=f(x)$. Is it always possible to "adjoin" a parameter $t$ i.e s.t $y(t)=f(x(t))$?

Comment: The question is not that clear to me, yes you can, the same way that if you have $f$ you can create $f \circ g$ with another function ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you are just composing the function $f:A\to B$ with another function mapping some set $X\to A$ (denoted $x$ in the second formula). Yes, with the range of $x$ matching the domain of $f$ you can always do that. One trivial way to do that is to set $x(t)=t, x:A\to A$.

Comment: Yes. In that case you have depended both $x$ and $y$ to a third party $t$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct definition of a function require not only a ''rule'' $f(\cdot)$ that gives a value $y=f(x)$, but also a set $X$ that is the domain of the function (and a set $Y$ that is its codomain)

$$
f:X\to Y \qquad y=f(x)
$$

now, if $x$ is a function of some other variable $t$ this function is:
$$
g:T\to X \qquad x=x(t)=g(t)
$$

and, if we want the composite function $f(x(t))=f(g(t))$ to have the same domain of the original $f$ than $g$ must be a [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) function.